# Creating a List(object) in an ActiveX dll project, in Visual Basic 6.0 to use in c# project

Tags: c#, list, vb6, components, activex

I want to create a List in an ActiveX component project in Visual Basic 6.0. Then I will get

the list from a c# project.

Thanks

Comment: OK.  Whats the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With c#, you can create your own controls. You have different possibilities to do that.

1. Derive as class from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and add your functionality. This is the most flexible, however most complicated approach.
2. Derive as class from an existing control which comes close to what you want to do and adapt it (e.g. by overriding `OnPaint`).
3. Add a `UserControl` to your project. You can place other controls on a `UserControl` much like you place controls on a form.

You can do this in your main assembly (.exe); however, if you do this in a class library (.dll), then you can use it much like an ActiveX control. In .NET, you do not need the "magic" of an ActiveX control. Controls are just classes that derive from `Control`.

---

I often derive my own controls from `ListBox` and override `OnPaint` in order to display the items in a different way, by adding icons, by using different colors or by displaying text on multiple lines.

This is an example of a `ListBox` that I customized this way

[image: Example of customized ListBox]

---

**EDIT**:

Are you looking for an alternative to the `Collection` type of VB6? In C# or VB.NET you use collections of the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. `List<T>` for lists and `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` for storing key/value pairs.

Example of lists:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Hello");
list.Add("World");

Console.WriteLine(list[0]); // ==> "Hello"
Console.WriteLine(list[1]); // ==> "World"

foreach (string s in list) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
// Output:  Hello
//          World
```

Example of key value pairs:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
dict.Add("Sunday", 1);
dict.Add("Monday", 2);
dict.Add("Tuesday", 3);
dict.Add("Wednesday", 4);
dict.Add("Thursday", 5);
dict.Add("Friday", 6);
dict.Add("Saturday", 7);

Console.WriteLine(dict["Wednesday"]); // ==> 4

int daynum;
if (dict.TryGetValue("Christmas", out daynum)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Christmas has the day number {0}.", daynum);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Christmas is not a weekday.");
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

In order to use an ActiveX created with VB6 in .NET, you need the command line utility `TlbImp` provided in the .NET SDK. Call it like this

```
    tlbimp MyActiveX.dll /out:MyCsharp.dll
```

Then you can use `MyCsharp.dll` like any other .NET dll. See [C# and ActiveX DLLs by Anand Narayanaswamy](http://www.csharp-station.com/Articles/CSharpAndActiveXDlls.aspx).

Comment: Hi Olivier, List means like an object list in Visual Basic 6. I created ActiveX dll project in Visual Basic 6. I have records in a do loop. I will add these records to a list, and then when I referenced this dll(which is created in VB6) in a c# project, I will use the list of records.

Comment: Bertan, you should put more effort in asking the question. What are you trying to achieve? Could you provide an example of the code you have written so far in VB6? Someone has downvoted your question because it is incomprehensible. Nevertheless, I updated my answer. You can do much more things with c# than with VB6. Trying to solve c# problems by using VB6 seems very weird to me.

Comment: Hi, Olivier. I use VB6, because I have a software development kit, for a finger print device, written in VB6. That Sdk does not working correctly in C#, directly. So I try to wrap that sdk into an ActiveX dll project with VB6. Then I will use that dll in my C# project.

Comment: I added an explanation on how to use an ActiveX in c#. Your question should probably have been, "How can I use an ActiveX created with VB6 in .NET?" and has nothing to do with lists.

Comment: That title is not exactly what I am looking for, I still want to pass finger print device record list from VB6(ActiveX Project) side to C# side, but it is also an issue for me. I used TlbImp to turn my unmanaged code to managed .net code, it is successfull, but in c# side when I import my dll into a c# project,and try to use my methods, it throws an InvalidCastException ->

Comment: The Eception is; Unable to cast COM object of type 'PIO.clsPdksClass' to interface type 'PIO._clsPdks'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{335F37A9-B674-484E-92CD-2E47A521694C}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). I searched internet for this exception,but I have not find it yet. Do you know any source about that exception. Thanks a lot for your patience :)

Comment: When I registered my old, ActiveX dll, with regsvr32 command, the exception is gone. I will test my codes with device. I will inform you. Thanks again Olivier.